# Qt load indicator by animated image (aka preloader) or alternative?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.4

I want to display an animated loader image on my table view while loading. The screenshot below shows an impression.

I have used an animated gif for that, displayed by `setStyleSheet` as centered background image.

[image: Loader image]

I face two issues:

1. The gif is displayed, but not animated. Is it possible to display an animated gif as background image (via stylesheet)? Remark: In general an animated gif is possible as shown in  [Qt - How to show gif(animated) image in QGraphicsPixmapItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769766/qt-how-to-show-gifanimated-image-in-qgraphicspixmapitem) but there seems to be no animated `gif` with style sheets [Animated Gif static in QStyleSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11873372/356726)
2. I have problems to clear the image once loading is done. If I clear the stylesheet with `setStyleSheet("")` then it is still displayed. The only trick working for me is to override it as 1 pixel transparent image

Is there a solution to those issues or even a better approach (overlay widget? / specialized Qt widget for that)?

(My code exampled with Qt 5.4 / Win7)

---

Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26958738/356726 shows how such a gif can be animated, but I have no idea to use that in such a kind of overlay / background style.

Comment: You can draw radial gradient then mask with an alpha mask. When it's done just stop drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QProgressIndicator](https://github.com/mojocorp/QProgressIndicator) insted of gif animation.

PS: it says that it Qt4, but it works with Qt5.

Comment: Interesting hint, but it seems to be a normal widget. Does it work as overlay, as I want to display the indicator as part of the table view.  Or is there an easy way to center a widget over an existing one (I am not aware of any).

Comment: Widget is an example. Main idea is the paint function. You can basically reimplement paintEvent for your table. It would be much faster than gif. And because it's QPainter-based implementation - you can draw it everywhere.

If you want to paint indicator on widget and then place it over another widget - you can use resizeEvent to update it's position.

Comment: Following that idea, but got some issues. Follow up created: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32653267/356726

Comment: With the paint issue solved, I use a modified version of `QProgressIndicator` painted itself into the `QTableView` viewport.

Answer (score 1):

[QtWaitingSpinner](https://github.com/snowwlex/QtWaitingSpinner) is also an elegant solution.

[Python Version here.](https://github.com/z3ntu/QtWaitingSpinner)